# Pasar un objeto entre controladores

Tags: angularjs

Estoy intentando que dos controladores compartan un objeto, es decir, desde una vista quiero mandar un objeto a otra vista, pero no consigo que en la vista que recibe este objeto lo obtenga. Para ello he creado un servicio:

```
angular.module("panelYerrandApp").service('ItemComercioSV', function () { 
// this.comercio = item
this.itemcomercio = [];

this.setItemComercio = function (item) {
    this.itemcomercio = item;
}

this.getItemComercio = function () {
    return this.itemcomercio;
}
});
```

En ambos controladores inyecto el servicio, desde una vista asigno el item y desde la otra lo recupero pero me aparece 'undefined'. ¿Esto se puede hacer?

Comment: Agrega el código de los controllers donde asignas los items y donde los recuperas.

Comment: Vas por el camino correcto, asegurate que todas las dependecias estan bien y que no hay errores de mayusucula/minuscula.

Comment: Para estos inconvenientes, normalmente utilizo LocalStorage. Si bien no es una buena praxis, viene siendo una solución rápida si sabes utilizarla.

Answer (score 1):

Partiendo de la base de [esta respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12009408/1468942):

Para enviar variables entre múltiple controladoras se utiliza un servicio para inyectar en cualquier controladora:

**Servicio de ejemplo:**

```
angular.module('myApp', [])
    .service('sharedProperties', function () {
        var property = 'First';

        return {
            getProperty: function () {
                return property;
            },
            setProperty: function(value) {
                property = value;
            }
        };
    });
```

**Utilización:**

```
function Ctrl2($scope, sharedProperties) {
    $scope.prop2 = "Second";
    $scope.both = sharedProperties.getProperty() + $scope.prop2;
}
```

Y un [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/b2fCE/1/) que lo utiliza.

Answer (score 0):

Lo que te cuestionas, depende del contexto.

En el caso de trabajar con estado (ui.router), es mas facil el paso de parametros a traves del estado, si los 2 controladores esta en la misma vista y requieren de una variable en comun, lo que yo recomiendo es el uso de providers. si bien el servicio va a funcionar, pero no es la mejor practica.

te recomiendo que leas mas acerca de buenas practicas en angular del señor John Papa en el siguiente link : https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide/blob/master/a1/README.md